# Drupal composer update/install not working

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I wanna install drupal project dependencies and modules but when I run `composer install` or `update` I get this [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJieQ.png)

I have tried with `--no-plugins`

I also have tried `composer update laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin magento/composer-root-update-plugin`

I know it says

> it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0")

but I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

This problem can happen if you try to install packages that are not yet compatible with Composer v2. Try to downgrade to v1 with the following command:

`composer self-update --1`

Afterwards, it should be possible to upgrade your packages. As Composer v1 [won't be supported forever](https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/), check whether you can do these upgrades in the next time